# percentage distribution - JavaScript Math.random()

Tags: javascript, math, random

I have percentages **10%**, **20%** and **70%** to decide which action to take. I have two ways to decide: #1 let a new Math.random() decide every time or #2 keep one Math.random() result. See the code i run in the console (note the `rand1` and `rand2` methods):

```
console.log('chart1');
var chart1;
var rand1 = function() {
    if (Math.random() <= 0.1) chart1[0]++;
    else if (Math.random() <= 0.2) chart1[1]++;
    else chart1[2]++;
};
var runs = 10000;
for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    chart1 = [0,0,0];
    for (var i = 0; i < runs; i++) rand1();
    var log = [];
    for (var k = 0; k < chart1.length; k++) {
        log[k] = Math.round(chart1[k] / runs * 100);
    }
    console.log(log);
}

console.log('chart2');
var chart2;
var rand2 = function() {
    var rand = Math.random();
    if (rand <= 0.1) chart2[0]++;
    else if (rand >= 0.1 && rand <= 0.3) chart2[1]++;
    else chart2[2]++;
};
var runs = 10000;
for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    chart2 = [0,0,0];
    for (var i = 0; i < runs; i++) rand2();
    var log = [];
    for (var k = 0; k < chart2.length; k++) {
        log[k] = Math.round(chart2[k] / runs * 100);
    }
    console.log(log);
}
```

it produces

```
chart1
[10, 18, 72]
[10, 17, 72]
[11, 17, 72]
[10, 18, 72]
[10, 18, 72]
[10, 18, 72]
[10, 17, 73]
[10, 18, 72]
[10, 18, 72]
[10, 18, 71]

chart2 
[9, 20, 71]
[10, 21, 70]
[10, 19, 71]
[10, 20, 70]
[10, 19, 71]
[10, 20, 70]
[10, 20, 70]
[9, 20, 71]
[10, 20, 71]
[9, 20, 71]
```

And i dont get why `chart1` tends to `..18, 72]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the math is wrong. If you want to use a new random number in the second comparison, then it should be true for 20/90 of the cases, not 20/100. So:

```
var rand1 = function() {
  if (Math.random() < 0.1) chart1[0]++;
  else if (Math.random() < 0.222222222222222) chart1[1]++;
  else chart1[2]++;
};
```

It works if you don't use a new random number, because then you know that the number is in the range 0.1 .. 1.0 when you come to the second condition, so if it's less than 0.3 that's 20/90 of the cases. If you pick a new random number, that number is instead in the range 0.0 .. 1.0.

Comment: Damn, you are right. Actually its quite simple. If i sum up 18 and 72 i get 90. And WITHIN 90 - 18 to 72 is a 20% to 80% ratio. 18/90=0.2=20%. Got it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Consider the probability of generating a number in the second column in the first chart. You start by generating a number with a 10% probability of ending up in the first column. If this number is *not* place in the first column, of which there is a 90% chance, there is a 20% probability of it winding up in the second column. Your total probability of a number being placed in the second chart is then 0.9 * 0.2 = 0.18. Add some random variability and you get something around 18.

For the third column, you have 100 - 10 - 18 = 72.

If the probability of accepting the second value were changed to 2/9 instead of 2/10, we would have a total probability of acceptance of 9/10 * 2/9 = 2/10, or 20%, which is what you want.

Comment: Yeah. Basic math. Shame on me! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

well..why are you calling Math.random() again in the if condition.????
use like this.

```
var rand1 = function(){
var number = Math.random();
if(number <= 0.1) chart1[0]++;
else if(number <= 0.3) chart1[1]++;
else chart1[2]++;
};
```

now this will give correct output as you desired

Comment: Yes, that's what the OP is doing in the second chart, and the question was why there is a difference.